# what's the right way to draw contour lines on map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour, levelplot

I have a data frame in R like this:

```
lat     lon     pressure
70.93   -8.67   991.1
70.93   -8.67   990.1
78.92   11.93   989.7
74.52   19.02   984.3
74.52   19.02   984.8
67.25   14.4    982.3
67.25   14.4    984.4
63.7     9.6    986.6
63.7     9.6    986.5
56.5     3.2    996.3
56.5     3.2    994.6
58.87    5.67   992.2
58.87    5.67   991.8
65.54   22.11   988.0
65.54   22.11   982.0
62.53   17.44   991.2
```

I'm trying to draw a contour lines (isobar) on the map:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Here you can find the full data:
# https://www.dropbox.com/s/zuzeo17uggam99n/pressure_data.rds?dl=0
data <- readRDS("pressure_data.rds")

col <- c("#0000FF", "#00FFFF", "#00FF00", "#FFFF00", "#FFA500", "#FF0000")

mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50")
mp <- ggplot() +   mapWorld
mp <- mp + geom_density2d(data = data, aes(x = lon, y = lat)) +
     stat_density2d(data = data, aes(x = lon, y = lat,  fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..),
                    size = 0.01, bins = 16, geom = 'polygon') +
     scale_fill_gradientn(colours=col) + scale_alpha(range = c(0.2, 1))
mp
```

I get this [image: this].

Why the legend looks like 1.0е-04, 7.5е-05, etc? Pressures are in the range 583.5 to 1031.3.

How to get right contours, like this? 
[image: Like this]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `stat_contour()` and define `pressure` as `z`. Right now, ggplot has no idea you are trying to plot pressures, it merely knows about `lon` and `lat` and is looking how many observations of those you have. The legend refers to probability density estimates.